# How to make sure get newest CR(custom resource) status of a CR?

Tags: kubernetes, client-go, kubernetes-custom-resources

I have a CRD and it's operator, when CR updated, operator will modify the status of this CR to `updating` from `done`. After all operation done, operator will change the status into `done` again.

I wrote another go client program to modify this CR and wait until it done. But when I query the status of this CR just after send the request to k8s, the status is still `done`(the operator is not fast enough to change it to `updating` before this), so the program will consider it already updated, but in fact, it wasn't.

My solution is when updating the CR, set the status to `unknown` first, and let operator modify it to `updating`. But I think this is not a good way.

Anyone know the best practice of this situation? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look for the time at which the status was set to 'done', which is hopefully something your custom resource provides in its status conditions/history. If it's earlier than the start of your program, then it certainly isn't the right 'done'.

Native Kubernetes resources such as Pods follow this pattern. See the following link and note the 'lastTransitionTime' field. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-conditions

This reporting of a change may also happen through the emitting of a Kubernetes event, depending on the custom resource.

Comment: Thank you very much, this truely solved my problem!

But I still got a question: I read the code of helm. I found that helm waiting resource with condition but the code didn't check the time of condition, why my problem didn't bother helm?

https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/15d116b8548f59959fe9f2fafdaf7c6de8db3ea0/pkg/kube/ready.go#L230-L238

Comment: @dayeguilaiye It's a guess but I suppose that any new Pod involved in a Helm install or upgrade must be fresh and not have existed before, so it's unnecessary to check the times.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But helm upgrade will update the resources in chart instead of create when those resources already exist in cluster. So this problem seem should happen to helm too, and that's the reason why I'm confused

Comment: I have a suspicion this is a bug/assumption in Helm. I've tested it and running `helm upgrade [...] --wait` on a chart that creates a single Pod with a `readinessProbe` that won't return true for at least 5 seconds returns immediately, despite the analogous `helm install [...] --wait` command taking at least 5 seconds. Repeating this same process but with a Deployment instead of a Pod (the Deployment having the same PodSpec as the aforementioned Pod) takes a predictably long amount of time as it waits for all the newly created Pods to become ready.

Comment: So the assumption on the part of the Helm developers is that you will never be upgrading a Pod with Helm and hoping that `--wait` works as you might expect. However, for workloads that specify Pods (like Deployments), all the Pods that result from an upgrade are created new. Therefore, just checking if the Pod has ever been ready is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you very much, I found this bug/assumption too! So maby this problem can only be solved by the way you mentioned in answer, check the lastTransition field.